# heroku app dashboard logs | heroku file system

Tags: node.js, heroku, logging

My heroku app dashboard logs are not showing all my application's logs.
Could there be something about the heroku file system that is causing this?

Answer (score 0):

System logs are not exposed by Heroku - only your application logs. Basically, anything that is written to STDOUT will appear in your app logs.

Comment: Hi @john-beynon , unfortunately STDOUT (console.log statements) are the ones not appearing in my heroku dashboard logs. Just to give more context to my question....I have a node.js app that creates a temporary file under /tmp and then uses that file for a specific purpose. So I added print statements (that show the contents of the file) in my application to ensure that the file is actually created. These print statements work perfectly on my localhost /development environment but when I deploy on heroku, there is no logging shown for the creation of my temporary files!